# Resizing char array not always working

Tags: c++, pointers, resize, character-arrays

In a custom string class called `Str` I have a function `c_str()` that just returns the private member `char* data` as `const char* c_str() const { return data; }`. This works when called after I create a new `Str` but if I then overwrite the `Str` using `cin`, calling `c_str()` on it only sometimes works, but always works if I `cin` a bigger `Str` than the original.

```
Str b("this is b");
cout << b.c_str() << endl;

cin >> b;
cout << b.c_str() << endl;
```

Here the first `b.c_str()` works but if I attempt to change `Str b` to just 'b' on the `cin >> b;` line then it outputs 'b' + a bit of garbage. But if I try to change it to 'bb' it usually works, and if I change it to something longer than "this is b", it always works.

This is odd because my istream operator (which is friended) completely deallocates the `Str` and ends up allocating a new char array only 1 char larger for each char it reads in (just to see if it would work, it doesn't). So it seems like returning the array after reading in something else would return the new array that `data` is set it.

Relevant functions:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Str& s) {
    delete[] s.data;
    s.data = nullptr;
    s.length = s.limit = 0;

    char c;
    while (is.get(c) && isspace(c)) ;

    if (is) {
        do s.push_back(c);
        while (is.get(c) && !isspace(c));

        if (is)
            is.unget();
    }
    return is;
}

void Str::push_back(char c) {
    if (length == limit) {
        ++limit;
        char* newData = new char[limit];

        for (size_type i = 0; i != length; ++i)
            newData[i] = data[i];

        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
    data[length++] = c;
}
```

With `push_back()` like this, the array never has a capacity larger than what it holds, so I don't see how my `c_str()` could output any memory garbage.

Comment: How does your `c_str()` function look like? If you want to return a null-terminated C string you need to make sure that there is a null character stored at the end of the character sequence. You don't add a null character in your `push_back()`, i.e., you'll need to add the null character somewhere else.

Comment: Not looking to have my `Str`s null-terminated, just wanted `c_str()` to correctly output what was stored in `data`, but my `c_str()` is just: `const char* c_str() const { return data; }`

Comment: What do you think `operator <<(std::ostream&, const char*)` is expecting if **not** a null-terminated string? "Not looking to have my Strs null-terminated" makes zero sense if you expect `c_str()` to behave as the stream inserter expects.

Comment: That's true, but I overloaded the `ostream` operator:
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Str& s) {
    for (Str::size_type i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i)
        os << s[i];
    return os;
}` where the `size()` function returns the `length` member from `Str`

Comment: Which means *nothing* when you're sending `c_str()` to an output stream. At that point the target stream has no clue you're giving it anything besides a `const char *` and your operator override for `const Str&` isn't even in the equation. Your "but" is Dietmar's second option, and if so, you would be better off throwing out `c_str()` entirely.

Comment: Oh ok that does make sense, didn't realize `const char*` outputs until null is found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `push_back()` in the question and the `c_str()` in the comment, there is no guarantee that the C-string returned from `c_str()` is null-terminated. Since a `char const*` doesn't know the length of the string without the null-terminator this is the source of the problem!

When allocating small memory objects you probably get back one of the small memory object previously used by you string class and that contains non-null characters, causing the printed character appear as if it is of what is the length to first null byte found. When allocating bigger chunks you seem to get back "fresh" memory which still contains null character, making the situation appear as if all is OK.

There are basically two ways to fix this problem:

1. Add a null-terminator before returning a `char const*` from `c_str()`. If you don't care multi-threading for now, this can be done in the `c_str()` function. In contexts where multi-threading matters it is probably a bad idea to make any mutations in `const` member functions as these would introduce data races. Thus, the C++ standard string classes add the null-terminator in one of the mutating operations.
2. Do not support a `c_str()` function at all but rather implement an output operator for your string class. This way, no null-termination is needed.

Comment: Oh ok, so since my `c_str()` returns a `const char*` that will just output starting with `data` but not ending until a null character is found? It looks like in basic_string.h `c_str()` returns a `const _CharT*`, does it rely on other functions for creating/changing strings to ensure they are always null-terminated?

Comment: The `std::basic_string<_CharT, ...>` always makes sure that the stored string is null-terminated (that wasn't the case prior to C++11): only non-`const` member functions can change the string representation and adding a null character would be a violation of this rule. The reason this constrained was added in C++11 is that multi-threading was added and the thread-safety guarantees made by the C++ standard classes rely on `const` member functions not making any changes to the object.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize how important null-termination is, made some changes that you mentioned in another one of my posts so my underlying container is always null-terminated, everything working fine now! :D